# qTune function is not identifying any neighbours for the spots

Tags: rna-seq

I am trying to perform Single Cell Analysis. I have constructed the SingleCellExperiment Object successfully with the counts data and coordinates data. SpatialPreprocess of the object was successful. However, the Qtune function is not able to find the neighbours for the spots. I get the following message.

[image]

Can someone suggest the possible reason for this?

I have tried using

sceq <- qTune(sce)